# when use the case in order by then it give the error message “conversion failed”

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have used the case in order by when `complaint status id = 1` then sort data by complaint date and `complaint status id = 2` then sort the data by Resolved on date and when `complaint status id = 3` then sort data by resolved on date

But when the `complaint status id = 3` then it give the error message:

> conversion failed when converting date and / or time form character
>    string

Order by in query

```
order by case @ComplaintstatusId when 1 then a.complaintDate
                                  when 2 then a.resolvedDate
                                  when 3 then a.resolvedDate
                                  else 1 end desc
```

Comment: What are the datatype of `a.complaintDate` and `a.resolvedDate` ? are both dates?

Comment: Given full query to check this problem. And It should be error in data not query.

Comment: which rdbms is this for? from your error it looks like sql server

Comment: data type "Datetime2"

Comment: @stevealan -please post your entire query, this issue might be somewhere else

Comment: A case expression's all returned types must be type compatible, and 1 (numeric) is not type compatible with the date type.

Answer (score 1):

You are projecting 1 of 3 dates, or an integer from your case when statement - this won't fly - all returns from the `case when` must be of the same type. I'm not sure what you are trying to do with `1`, but for example:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable a
order by 
    case @ComplaintstatusId 
        when 1 then a.complaintDate
        when 2 then a.resolvedDate
        when 3 then a.resolvedDate
        else CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -- same type as the others
    end desc
```

**Edit**

I'm guessing that by `1 desc` you mean ordering desc by the first column <del>(which is of a different type, such as `*char`, hence the error)</del>. What you can do then is use [two column orderings](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7301/how-to-make-conditional-ordering-for-two-or-more-columns), mutually exclusive from eachother:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable a
order by 
    case @ComplaintstatusId 
        when 1 then a.complaintDate
        when 2 then a.resolvedDate
        when 3 then a.resolvedDate
    end desc,
    case when @ComplaintstatusId < 1 or @ComplaintstatusId > 3
       then MyCol -- First column in your select list
    end desc;
```

AFAIK you'll need to explicitly name column 1.

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4b7d7/2)